# Have pre defined menus when developing a theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to develop a theme with customizable menus, like a header with menu options and footer with menu options.

In my theme menu page right now, in "Select a menu to edit" there are only 2 menus that are editable and only because I manually added the 2nd menu. But in another theme I am trying to make similar to, there are tons of pre made menus in "Select a menu to edit" and I did not add any of those.

how can I add pre defined selectable menu options for my theme?

Like a footer would have 4 different parts, header would have a part etc..

[image: I want more menus here]

I want more menus here

[image]

I know how to add more here!

Comment: What are you trying to do, create new menu locations?

Comment: Yes i believe that is what i want @vard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new menu location AND a menu, add this code to your *functions.php* file:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu( 'header_menu', 'Menu header' );
  // change this to the desired menu name
  $menu_header = wp_create_nav_menu('Main menu');
  if($menu_header > 0) {
      // set the new menu location
      set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' , array( 'header_menu' => $menu_header ) );
  }
}
```

It will register a new menu location, then create a blank menu inside it. If you need to add items inside that menu, check on [`wp_update_nav_menu_item`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_nav_menu_item/) function.

Then to display it in your template (like *header.php* in this case) :

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'header_menu' )); ?>
```

Comment: Hi I just edited my post to have images of what I want. That code adds more menu settings...I want menus in general.

Comment: The `register_my_menu` does exactly what you want: it provide new location in the checkox list from your second screen.

Comment: How can I make it so its pre defined? So the user doesn't have to set up the footer menu, only add options to it?

Comment: You mean you don't want him to create the menu through the "create a new menu" link? If so you need to add some predefined links inside that preregistered menu?

Comment: Like in the first image theres the dropdown box for menu selection. In a theme I am trying to replicate, the list is already populated and I didn't add anything. Same with the 2nd image, the list. The user can customize the menus however they want. I want to add that functionality to my theme.